# Book involving a supernatural adolescent boy, maybe ages quickly, possibly dies

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, space

In 1991/2 I read this book that involved a supernatural boy who emerged somehow, or arrived in a space craft, who was befriended.  The being was an adolescent boy, and physically superior to the one who befriended him, but was possibly dying?  Maybe he did die?  I think I remember a foot race, maybe a heart issue?  The book could have been from the 80s or 50s, who knows?  I didn't want to read it, but the teacher had it in her loaner collection.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: You can accept an answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Comment: Mark Twain's _[The Mysterious Stranger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mysterious_Stranger)_  comes to mind.

Answer (score 0):

This might be *[Born Into Light](https://www.publishersweekly.com/978-0-590-40710-6)* by Paul Samuel Jacobs

[image: Front cover of *Born Into Light*]

> Told in the first-person, this old-fashioned science fiction novel looks back upon the childhood of an old scientist. The narrator has puzzled over certain events for more than seven decades, events set into motion one morning when he was 10. A child appears out of a flash of light in their backyard and, believed to be feral or abandoned, is taken in by his family. But, before long, the child, Ben, reveals extraordinary intelligence and development. He matures quickly, finishes college in two years and ages much quicker than the narrator. The narrator's stepfather begins to investigate the other children who appeared on Earth in the same mysterious fashion as Ben; an alien race has seeded the human population with some of their own, strengthening their bloodlines and stimulating human progress. Ben gathers together as many of the aliens and their half-human offspring as he can find, and, in a flash of light, they return to the stars.

It previously came up at [Science fiction about found children who are adopted into families and age quickly](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/152176/science-fiction-about-found-children-who-are-adopted-into-families-and-age-quick), where they reference the weak heart, the foot race, and the death. I remembered it from there, but unable to find it through a site search, I instead combed my library history. Fortunately, it was only 2017ish that I checked it out, so only about 10 pages of results.

Comment: This is the book, thank you very much!